# How to build a complex View Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I was wondering if anyone could help me with the building of my View Model...

I have three parent models, Users, Profiles, and Projects

On a view, I would like to pass a model that has the user's information, their profile information, and their projects information...

So far my View Model looks like this...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProDevPortMVC3.ViewModels
{
    public class PortfolioViewModel
    {
        public int ProfileID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string ProfileFirstName { get; set; }
        public string ProfileLastName { get; set; }
        public string ProfileEmail { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> ProfileContactNo { get; set; }
        public string ProfileCity { get; set; }
        public string ProfileState { get; set; }
        public string ProfileCountry { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePhotoPath { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePhotoName { get; set; }
        public string ProfileBio { get; set; }
        public string ProfileMissionStatement { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePrivacySetting { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ProfileBlog> ProfileBlogs { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ProfileForum> ProfileForums { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Projects model/table has one-to-many child tables... and I need all of their information as well in the View Model... Here are the child tables...

ProjectCodeSamples
ProjectDownloads
ProjectScreenShots
ProjectTechnologiesUseds

Here is my Controller Action Method thus far...

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var profile = db.Profiles.SingleOrDefault(p => p.UserID == id);
    var profileBlogs = db.ProfileBlogs.Where(p => p.ProfileID == profile.ProfileID);
    var profileForums = db.ProfileForums.Where(p => p.ProfileID == profile.ProfileID);
    var projects = db.Projects.Where(p => p.ProfileID == profile.ProfileID);
    var viewModel = new PortfolioViewModel
    {
        ProfileFirstName = profile.ProfileFirstName,
        ProfileLastName = profile.ProfileLastName,
        ProfileEmail = profile.ProfileEmail,
        ProfileContactNo = profile.ProfileContactNo,
        ProfileCity = profile.ProfileCity,
        ProfileState = profile.ProfileState,
        ProfileCountry = profile.ProfileState,
        ProfilePhotoPath = profile.ProfilePhotoPath,
        ProfilePhotoName = profile.ProfilePhotoName,
        ProfileBio = profile.ProfileBio,
        ProfileMissionStatement = profile.ProfileMissionStatement,
        ProfilePrivacySetting = profile.ProfilePrivacySetting,
        ProfileBlogs = profileBlogs.Where(p => p.ProfileID == profile.ProfileID),
        ProfileForums = profileForums.Where(p => p.ProfileID == profile.ProfileID),
        Projects = projects.Where(p => p.ProfileID == profile.ProfileID)
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

So, how do I continue or what do I do from here?

EDIT: I forgot to add that the Project Child Tables have a foreign key ProjectID that connect them to the Projects table...

Here is the final View code for it to work...

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
{
    <p>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)
    </p>

    foreach (var subItem in item.ProjectDownloads)
    {
        <pre>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subItem.ProjectDownloadPath)
        </pre>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use the Project model in your ViewModel you can simply access the Project's child tables in the view.

For example, you should be able to do the following:

```
foreach(var item in model.Projects)
{
    foreach(var download in item.ProjectDownloads)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: oh might need to Include the child tables in your LINQ statement. `Projects = projects.Include("ProjectDownloads").Where(p => p.ProfileID == profile.ProfileID)`.

Comment: Tried that just now, didn't work either... Just so you know, the Project Child tables, i.e., ProjectDownloads... They don't have a field called ProfileID, just ProjectID

Comment: .Include just makes it so the related entities are loaded as well and not ignored due to lazy loading. the "Where" clause is still applied to the Projects Entity. Since Projects is a collection too, you need to select the project first. So Model.Projects.ProjectDownloads won't work - my bad for not reading properly. So rather `foreach (var subitem in item.ProjectDownloads)` within the outer foreach.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I get this error on the View page when I  put that in the Controller method... "'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<ProDevPortMVC3.Project>' does not contain a definition for 'ProjectDownloads' and no extension method 'ProjectDownloads' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumberable<ProDevPortMVC3.Project>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I got it, actually you don't need the LINQ that you provided, simply reference the loop variable in the View page... Thank you for your help.

Comment: i edited my answer for clarification. this is where lazy loading should do its magic assuming you use Entity Framework.